# Calculate total working hours of employee based swipe in/ swipe out using oracel sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I was recently given a task to calculate an employee's total office hours based on his card swipe in/swipe out. I have the following data :

```
id  gate_1  gate_2  gate_3  gate_4
100     null    null    null    9:00
100     null    13:30   null    null
100     null    null    16:00   null
100     null    null    18:00   null
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/84gUD.png)

Here, the employee 100 comes in via gate_4 at 9 am and takes a break at 13:30 and goes out using gate_2. Then he comes back at 16:00 using gate_3 and leave office at 18:00 using gate_3. So, how to calculate the total in office timing using this data ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is datatype of field `gate_1`?

Comment: It is timestamp.

Comment: preparing a `sqlfiddle.com` schema and data helps to get good answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As has been pointed out your data model is denormalized to not even satisfy [1st normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form). The first step is to correct that (doing so in a query). Then there is no indication as to swipe in or swipe out, therefore it must be assumed that the first swipe time is always in and the ins/outs always alternate properly. Finally there is no indication of multiple days being covered so the assumption is just 1 period.  **That is a lot of assumptions.**
Since an Oracle data type date contains time as well as the date and summing differences is much easier than with timestamps I convert timestamp to date in the first step of normalizing the data. Given all this we arrive at: (See [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e1cbd50883d366c002c86392c76d8b0b))

```
with normal (emp_id, inout_tm) as 
     ( select emp_id, cast(gate1 as date) 
         from emp_gate_time 
        where gate1 is not null
       union all 
       select emp_id, cast(gate2 as date) 
         from emp_gate_time 
        where gate2 is not null
       union all          
       select emp_id, cast(gate3 as date) 
         from emp_gate_time 
        where gate3 is not null
       union all         
       select emp_id, cast(gate4 as date) 
         from emp_gate_time 
        where gate4 is not null
     )
select emp_id, round(24.0*(sum(hours)),1) hours_in_office
  from ( select emp_id,(time_out - time_in) hours 
           from ( select emp_id, inout_tm time_in, rn
                       , lead(inout_tm) over(partition by emp_id order by inout_tm) time_out 
                    from ( select n.*
                                , row_number() over(partition by emp_id order by inout_tm) rn 
                             from normal n
                        )
                ) 
          where mod(rn,2) = 1 
       )  
 group by emp_id;
```

Items of Interest:

- [Subquery Factoring (CTE)](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/with-clause)
- [Date Arithmatic](https://sodocumentation.net/oracle/topic/2087/dates) - in Hours ...Difference Between Dates in hours ...
- [Oracle Analytic Functions](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174) - Row_number, lead

Answer (score 0):

You have a denormalized structure of your db scheme. You have fields as gate_1, gate_2 and etc. It's wrong way. The better way is following, you should have reference table of gates, for example like this

```
id|gate_name
--|---------
```

And your table with data for employee will be looks like this.

```
id_employee|id_gate|time
```

Then you can sort data in this table, and then count period of time between two consecutive rows.

Comment: In addition, the design should also include an 'in/out' indicator, so we can always know if the card swipe was coming or going.  Without that, it will be a certainty that the app will eventually lose track of the sequence.

Comment: @EdStevens Yes, I agree, it's looking better